# Breeze entity query returns object without null properties

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm using [breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/) in a SPA and have problem with entities loaded from server. Namely, entity created from metadata (using `metadataEntityType.createEntity()`) and added to entity manager has all of the properties like server-side model, ready for binding with knockout, and that is cool.

The problem is when I use `entityModel.EntityQuery.from("WorkOrders")`, the successCallback that I pass to its `.then` promise gets a data object with results property which contains an array of vanilla js objects where all of the properties with value == null are missing (this is exactly how server sends that data through the wire, but I suppose that it is how is meant to be because breeze has all metadata on the client and does not need all properties to know that they exist).

I have my custom constructor which can make full-fledged knockout object like the one from createEntity(), but I'm thinking that there must be a better way to let breeze handle this for me automatically. I'm not sure if I should add these objects to entity manager as I suppose they should be already there, and I registered my custom constructor to store using `entityManager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor`, but that does not change what success callback gets, it is always plain JSON just like it was sent from server.

**Update:** Code of method which is called on the server to return json payload is

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<WorkOrder> WorkOrders()
{
    return (IQueryable<WorkOrder>)_contextProvider.Context.WorkOrders;
}
```

As @Jay pointed in its answer & comment, that may be the cause of behavior. This is the JSON payload returned:

```
[{"$id":"1","$type":"WorkOrders.Domain.Models.WorkOrder, WorkOrders.Domain","Approved":false,"DateModified":"2013-01-02T22:31:20.897","RequestForEstimate":false,"Id":5}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was caused by a model being in a different namespace than the DbContext/ObjectContext that hosted it.  Previously this was documented as a known limitation.

As of v 0.83.2, breeze now allows model namespaces to be different from the DbContext/ObjectContext namespace.

Please confirm if this fixes the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, before update to 0.83.2 I resolved this by renaming context namespace, and after update it works with previous (original) namespace. Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking. Is it that you would like properties with a null value on the server returned to the breeze client with a value of null instead of being undefined, or am I missing the issue?

If this is the issue, I agree that what you want would be useful and I will add it as a feature request.

Another possibility that you might want to look at is to use the 3rd parameter to the 'registerEntityTypeCtor' method that lets you pass in an initialization function.  This function will be called once for each entity being constructed, 'after' it has already been materialized. This means that you can iterate over the properties or the object and set any that have a value of 'undefined' to 'null'

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, you understand the issue, but it does not matter to me if properties are sent from the server or not, I just want to have same object nevertheless if it is loaded from server or created anew. I will check if this third argument solves the problem for me. That means that constructor (either default or custom) is not called for objects that have come over the wire?

Comment: The registered constructor is always called, whether the entity is created or materialized by query. I suspect that your query is not returning entities. I assume you're using a Web API Controller; perhaps the action method ('MyCollection'?) is not returning an IQueryable of an entity type in metadata. "MyCollection" is an odd name for a query method.  A quick way to tell if you got an entity is to set a breakpoint in the success callback and check `data.results[0].entityType`; if that property returns `undefined`, you're not returning entities.

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem (it is not 'MyCollection', but it is not IQueryable also), but there is another issue that is preventing me from using IQueryable, I had to use IEnumerable, as that is separate issue I have created another question, to prevent going off topic on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14162181/408643 Do you think IEnumerable<MyType> is causing the problem?

Comment: I have also updated the question with contents of JSON payload returned from server, there is no entityType on result array elements.

Comment: Getting closer! You've confirmed that the client doesn't think the results are entities. It's treating them as arbitrary objects which it is happy to return but they aren't entities and Breeze won't put them in cache. Now the payload tells us that you are receiving JSON for a `WorkOrder` type. So let's find out if the client recognizes that type. What is 'x' after you run `var store = myEntityManager.metadataStore; store.getEntityType("WorkOrder");` in the success callback? Not good if null. If null, what is 'y' in `var y = store.getEntityTypes;`?

Comment: Btw, `IEnumerable` is not a factor. You can return a `WorkOrder` within any shape of result. The apparent problem is that the Breeze client isn't recognizing the JSON object as an entity type. Hence my previous comment.

Comment: metadataStore.GetEntityType("WorkOrder") returns ctor {shortName: "WorkOrder", namespace: "WorkOrders.Web.Models", defaultResourceName: "WorkOrders", name: "WorkOrder:#WorkOrders.Web.Models", dataProperties: Array[18]…}

Comment: Hah, I see the problem now, for some reason this metadata sees wrong namespace... I'm using POCO entities in another project/namespace for codefirst entities. Type is 'WorkOrders.Domain.Models.WorkOrder, WorkOrders.Domain', and in metadata it is returning 'Web.Models' namespace, this is namespace of EF context. Is this maybe a bug in breeze?

Comment: You could call it a bug ... or a documented feature :) See http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/entity-framework-dbcontext-0 where it says "Important: the classes can be in different assemblies but the model class namespace must match the DbContext/ObjectContext namespace." It goes on to explain a simple workaround. We suffer this because out-of-the-box metadata generation from EF doesn't support different namespaces for model and context. This is biting so many people that we may have to 'make it work'

Comment: Aaah, I have read this part of documentation, but I gone over this "Multiple assemblies" part because my brain was in search mode to find solution for this problem and it did not seem related, I did not even realize that I have this situation on my hands. I think you should copy your comment to an answer so we can close this question :) Thanks!

Comment: **The "same namespace" rule has been lifted as of Breeze v.0.83.2**